# how to access ajax response i.e data into php variable below defined div?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to access AJAX response i.e data into PHP variable below defined div.I want to access AJAX response in PHP.

```
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#search').click(function(){ 
            var drop=[]; 
            var drop1; 
            drop1= $('.drop').val(); 
            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'test.php', 
                type: 'post', 
                data: {drop1:drop1}, 
                success:function(data){ 
                } 
            }); 
            return false; 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

According to explanation given in comments:

1. Replace the type of button from *submit* to *button*.
2. Use the [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method to encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.